# How to run samplers sequentially in JMeter while running samplers by throughput?

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, api-testing, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I have `~10 scripts` in my `Test Plan`, which are dependent. (e.g. the 2nd request couldn't be passed if the 1st request is not passed - it is restriction of functionality).

My goal is to run `JMeter scripts` by certain percentage and / or RPS value. (I used for it [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) and [Throughput Shaping Timer Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) accordingly). By using these approaches, that requests executes randomly and as a result I got failures.

**I need to execute requests sequentially.**

Any ideas?

Comment: can try using **check the checkbox box  "Run Thread Groups Consecutively" in your test plan.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests are always been executed sequentially, i.e. each virtual user will execute Request 1 then Request 2 on first iteration then execute Request 1 and Request 2 on second iteration, etc. You can double check this using [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function to print the ID of the user and [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) to print the current thread group iteration.

[image: JMeter user id and thread group]

as you can see within the bounds of a single iteration a single user first executes Request 1 and then Request 2.